# Define custom exception handler in Java?

Tags: java, exception

*Well ! Thanks for having found the answer. I accepted the duplicate since it is exactly what I wanted and it is well explained.
Thanks to everybody for your answers :)*

Does anyone have advice or some idea on how to make a custom exception handler in Java ?

I mean modifying the standard Java exception handling method for **code-uncatched** `Exceptions`, `Errors` and more generically `Throwable`.

The PHP way to do this is to [define a custom exception handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php), but it seems there is no such way in Java.

The goal I would achieve is to insert a custom process in the Java error handling process :

Uncatched Throwable -> handling "outside my code" by the JVM -> my custom process -> resume JVM standard exception handling if wanted

Thanks to all for any idea or suggestion !

### Edit after your answers

Is there a way to generify this handler to all threads without declaring explicitly in each thread ?
I opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344294/java-uncaught-global-exception-handler-for-all-threads) for this topic.

Comment: Are you looking for `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just mind you, `Java` is `multithreaded`, and `exception` are related to their `threads`. If the `Exception` was uncaught you can use `thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

```
 thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("catching exception "+e.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Or you can use the `AOP` approach and define an `advice` to handle exceptions. Have a look at [AspectJ](https://dzone.com/articles/java-exception-translation).

**Note:** You need to be careful here because you might end up swallowing exceptions and having hard time figuring out the source of bugs

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Benj you are welcome  :)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done per thread like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Caught: " + e.toString());
        }
    });
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

With setting the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` it prints `Caught: java.lang.RuntimeException` instead of classic stack trace.

And Java 8 version with lambda:

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(
        (t, e) -> System.out.println("Caught: " + e.toString()));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(CustomHandler)`

The JVM allows you to customize that through the implementation of the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` interface

So basically

```
public class MyHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
     // handle the exception
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)