# Java uncaught global exception handler for ALL threads

Tags: java, exception

I asked a question about how to override the default Java Exception handling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343457/define-custom-exception-handler-in-java) and was told the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422366/java-uncaught-global-exception-handler).

The question is now : is there a way to generify this handler to all threads without declaring explicitly in each thread ?

I think it should be possible to get all threads in some way, then bind them the exception handler ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`.  As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) says:

> "By setting the default uncaught exception handler, an application can change the way in which uncaught exceptions are handled (such as logging to a specific device, or file) for those threads that would already accept whatever "default" behavior the system provided."

Obviously, if a Thread already has a (non-default) handler, then it won't be affected by a change to the default behavior.

---

> I think it should be possible to get all threads in some way, then bind them the exception handler ?

That's not necessary ... unless you want to change a thread's non-default handler.  If you really need to do that, you can find all threads by traversing the application's `ThreadGroup` hierarchy.  (Unless your app is sandboxed ...)

***Edit***

The thread list of the running app can be found using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018672/1579667) :

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler eh)` for that case if i got it right.

See [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method [setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) in `Thread`